# Cells are showing up Empty

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been struggling with this for about an hour now and don't understand why my cells aren't showing up in my tableview.I followed a tutorial and did exactly what he mentioned to do, but still having issues. I have set the reuse identifier to `main`, my delegate and dataSource are both set to self. I'm not getting any errors in the console and my data is coming through from my server. I printed out the title, description, etc. and it was all there. Help

```
#import "HTTPService.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "VideoCell.h"
#import "Video.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *videoList;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    self.videoList = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    [[HTTPService instance]getTutorials:^(NSArray * _Nullable 
dataArray, NSString * _Nullable errMessage)
     {
         if(dataArray){
             NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

             for (NSDictionary *d in dataArray){
                 Video *vid = [[Video alloc]init];
                 vid.videoTitle = [d objectForKey:@"title"];
                 vid.videoDescription = [d objectForKey:@"description"];
                 vid.thumbnailURL = [d objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
                 vid.videoIFrame = [d objectForKey:@"iframe"];

                 [arr addObject:vid];
             }

             self.videoList = arr;
             [self updateTableData];

         }
        else if(errMessage)
            NSLog(@"Alert to user: %@",errMessage);
    }];


}

-(void) updateTableData{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    VideoCell *vCell = (VideoCell*)[tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"main"];

    if(!vCell)
        vCell = [[VideoCell alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"here heree");
    return vCell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"hererrrr");
    return self.videoList.count;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(nonnull 
UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"Im in this bitch");
    Video *vid = [self.videoList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    VideoCell *vidCell = (VideoCell*)cell;
    [vidCell updateUI:vid];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

@end
```

Let me know if you need to see any of the import files!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you connect the `tableView` outlet in the storyboard or NIB?

Comment: The idiomatic thing to do is to configure your cell in `cellForRow:` rather than `willDisplayCell`.

Place a breakpoint in `willDisplayCell:`, is it getting called there?. Did you connect the storyboard to the outlet?

Comment: @MatusalemMarques I believe so! Check the image I just added.

Comment: @humbleCoder looks connected… Did you set breakpoints in your delegate methods and check if they're being called? Are you sure the problem is not in the VideoCell class?

Comment: @MatusalemMarques Yeah, but nothing shows up in the console, so it never gets called.

Comment: @humbleCoder Try connecting the tableView dataSource and delegate in the storyboard to the View Controller instead of setting them in viewDidLoad and check if that changes anything.

Comment: @MatusalemMarques Wow....I'm an idiot...the table view was linked to the tableView in the storyboard...I selected the wrong view from the image I provided....sorry about all that! But now I'm having an issue with the cells being squished. See pics

Comment: Put contraint in your cell in such a way that the upper top margin is bound with lower bottom of cell and then use two delegate methods of tableView.
1.estimatedHeightForRow_atindexpath , return average height of row in that.. like 500 or 400. Then..
2. Implement heightForRow_atIndexpath and return UITableViewCellAutomaticDimension.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, except for one thing. You forgot to register your cell to your tableView. Just put

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"VideoCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"main"];
```

in your viewDidLoad and everything will be fine. 
It is a common mistake that we all do.